# After Trigger execute before constraint check in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, constraints

I have After Insert/Update trigger on Table T1 which get the referential data for Col1 from T2 and does some work and insert it into another table.
The col1 is FK to Table T2.

When user insert the incorrect or non existing value into the Col1 and if trigger is disabled I am getting constraint error that is fine.

But when trigger is enabled and user insert the wrong value in Col1 trigger is getting fired and shows the 'no data found' error message.

Actually I am expecting the table to throw constraint error, but trigger is throwing it.

Please let me know your comments about this trigger behaviour.

Comment: This all makes perfect sense to you but it's a little confusing to the rest of us.  Please invest a little time to post some DDL statements and some test data.  Don't post the whole tables, just enough so that we can understand your scenario.

Comment: If the trigger is throwing an error, and you don't want it to, then you should consider it a bug in the trigger. Posting the trigger code as part of the question would be useful

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention whether you are using BEFORE or AFTER triggers. Please check the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i2013) for the [order of execution](http://psoug.org/reference/table_trigger.html):

- BEFORE statement
- BEFORE row
- CONSTRAINTS
- AFTER row
- AFTER statement

Comment: I'm pretty sure AFTER ROW runs before AFTER STATEMENT.

Comment: Actually the OP does say they are using an AFTER trigger (although not whether it is FOR EACH ROW or just statement level).

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the correct order of AFTER.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the trigger would have to be a `BEFORE` trigger. It will run prior to the constraints being checked. If the trigger raises `NO_DATA_FOUND`, then the constraint never gets checked. If the trigger is disabled, it is not run, so the constraint gets checked.